# spring-kafka listener signature

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I tried searching this over stackoverflow but couldnt find a reasonable answer. Im curious about signature of methods annotated with @Kafkalistener, is there any convention that we need to follow ?. What if we want to pass in a spring managed bean via method injection? Im trying to pass in a service class via method injection to a kafka listener -

```
private fun defaultListener(payload: ByteArray, @Headers messageHeaders: MessageHeaders, ack: Acknowledgment, callbackService: CallbackService) {
 // Do something
}
```

I get the following exception -

```
org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot handle message; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot convert from [[B] to [com.test.kafka-demo.service.CallbackService]
```

Works fine if I make the dependent service class Autowired.

Comment: You'd wire beans through the class constructor or fields, not the method signature

Answer (score 0):

All parameters in the listener method must be derived from the `ConsumerRecord` (or the record itself) + the consumer and/or the acknowledgment when using manual commits.

`@Payload` (or no annotation) is converted (if necessary) from the `record.value()`.

You can't add arbitrary bean references there.